# No plugin found for prefix 'http' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver

I was checking out a Selenium webdriver project ( from https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template) and i ran into this error even when there is no logic that was executed.

```
  $ mvn clean verify -Dit.test=Scraper2IT#testPractitionerUrl3 -Dbrowser=phantomjs -Durl.search=<<URL1>>  -Durl.practest = <<URL2>>
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 100.0 KB/sec)
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 59.7 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (22 KB at 38.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.672s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Feb 14 22:55:23 EST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'http' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository), central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2), sonatype-public-repository (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
'ref_page_id' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I found solutions for other 'prefix' errors but not one for either 'http' or 'https'

Which plugin is missing?

Comment: This happens if we give space before url in -Durl= "https://...". Remove space and try.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your dependency as below and then give it a try. Here is the link to the jar in [MVN repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.3).

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
               <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
               <version>4.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
        ...
    </build>
...
</project>
```